# Можно ли сказать "всорокером"?

Tags: орфография, словообразование, числительные, наречия

Как правильно сказать — **всорокером**?
Мы идем, и нас 40 человек (т. к. на 10 заканчивается, то ***-ером***). А дальше как?

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 3):

**...А дальше как?**

Дальше в литературном языке таких слов нет. Но теоретически подобное словообразование возможно, если слово образовано от собирательных числительных на **пять** или от обозначений десятков на **-дцать**, но не от сорок.

Подробнее можно прочитать [по этой ссылке](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5):

> **4.4.2.1. Наречия типа *вдвоем***
>   Наречия этого типа означают количество лиц, участвующих в ситуации (как в позиции подлежащего, так
>   и, реже, прямого дополнения: их застали вдвоём). Они образуются
>   прибавлением циркумфикса в-…-м к собирательным числительным (см. п.
>   4.1.4): вдвоём, **втроём, …, вдесятером**:   (55) *Вчерашний вечер она провела вдвоем с Георгием, сегодня за ранним ужином сидели
>   **ввосьмером**.* [Л. Улицкая. Медея и ее дети (1996)]
>
> Подобные образования теоретически возможны от собирательных
>   числительных на пять (*вдвадцатипятером*, при отсутствии
>   *двадцатьпятеро*, но не *вдвадцатичетвером*), от обозначений десятков на **-дцать** (*вдвадцатером*, *втридцатером*, *вшестидесятером*),
>   **но не от сорок**.
>
> По образцу данного типа наречий от местоимений-числительных образуются
>   просторечные **всколькером**, **вмногером**:   (56) *Какая разница
>   всколькером они там красят, подбирают и пр.* (Рязанский городской
>   форум)   (57) *Кооперативный режим не принесёт никаких сюрпризов –
>   проходим сингловые карты <т.е. сценарии игры, рассчитанные на одного
>   игрока> вмногером и честно делим награбленный хабар*. (Обзор игр на
>   ferra.ru)

Comment: Да, кроме примеров, к Вашему ответу добавить нечего. Соответственно - положительно.

Comment: *(вдвадцатипятером, при отсутствии двадцатьпятеро, но не вдвадцатичетвером)* - вот это я не понимаю. По мне так одинаково возможно (или невозможно).

Comment: Я тоже считаю, что такое словообразование идёт **не** от начальной формы числительного (напр. "вчетвером" образовано от _четверо_, а не _четыре_).

Answer (score 2):

К ответу со ссылкой (@grizzly) мне добавить нечего.
Приведу только несколько примеров.

*Таким образом, на Цейлоне мы натерпелись достаточно, хотя некоторые из наших стояли за то, чтобы вернуться на берег **вшестидесятером** или **восьмидесятером** и отомстить.*
[Д. Дефо. Приключения капитана Сингльтона](https://www.litmir.me/br/?b=217017&p=53)

*Никто не желал думать об альтернативах: ведь отбили же **впятидесятером** англичане, американцы и русские у проклятых боксеров Татарскую стену Посольского квартала.*
А. Одина, ‎Д. Дикий. Магистр

*Я решил, что нас попросят выйти на поверхность Луны, чтобы поднять махину – благо, на Луне слабое притяжение, мы **всемидесятером** бы справились!*
А. Чемезов. Билет на Луну в один конец

В блоге "Эхо Москвы" встретились  *втридцатипятером* и  *впятидесятипятером*.